# Get User Input From Lambda in AWS Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I was wondering if anybody has ever experimented with this issue I'm having and could give me any input on the subject.

As it stands right now I'm trying to see if there is a way to grab a users input through the AWS Connect. I understand that there is already a "Get User Input" block in the GUI that is available for me to use, unfortunately it does not offer the fine grain control I am looking for with requests and responses from Lex.

Right now I am able to [Post Content](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostContent.html) to Lex and get responses just fine, as well as output speech using [Amazon Polly via my Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html). This works great for things that do not require a user to have to give feedback for a question.

For example if a client asks

> "What time is my appointment?"

and we give back

> "Your appointment is for X at X time, would you like an email with
>   this confirmation?"

I want to be able to capture what the user says back within that same lambda.

So the interaction would go like so:

1. User asks a question.
2. Lambda POST's it to Lex and gets a response
3. Amazon Polly says the response - i.e: 'Would you like an email to confirm?'
4. Lambda then picks up if the user says yes or no - POST's info to Lex
5. Gets response and outputs voice through Polly.

If anybody has any information on this please let me know, thank you!

Comment: Is this your set up? Connect --> Lambda.A (capture input) --> Lex--Lambda.B (build response) --> Lex --> Lambda.A --> Polly --> Connect ....and your question is, How do you capture next user input in Lambda.A ? Please be more clear about your set up and some example code that you are using in Lambda currently.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you make so much complications to implement IVR system using Amazon Connect. I have done the complete IVR automated system to one of my biggest US banking client. Use the below procedure to achieve what you desire.

- Build a complete interactive lex bot(So that you can avoid amazon poly & using lex post content api). It is advised to build each bot has only one intent in it.
- In connect using "Get User Input" node map the lex bot which you have created earlier with the question to be asked "What time is my appointment?". Once this question has been played the complete control goes to lex and then you fulfilled your intent from lex side, you can come back to connect as like that.

Refer [AWS contact center](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/amazon-connect-with-amazon-lex-press-or-say-input/) for the clear idea.

Comment: Hi there. I understand that Lex handles all the calls to Polly within the "Get User Input" block and also handles intent mappings and such; to a certain degree. If you would like more fine grained control of something that Amazon does not implement such as capturing missed utterances when they occur, you would need all the information that the "Get User Input" does not handle / output.